# Can't switch dynamic keyspace

Tags: c#, cassandra, cassandra-sharp

I'm using "CassandraCSharpDriver" and I can not be in the same application to dynamically use different keyspaces. The class "Table" always connected to the first keyspace that I used to connect to the database. Here is an example of code:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {

                IDseCluster cluster = DseCluster.Builder()
                               .AddContactPoint("myPoint")
                               .Build();

                IDseSession session3 = cluster.Connect("keyspace_1");
                Row row3 = session3.Execute("select * from user_by_id").First();
                Console.WriteLine("keyspace_1 without table " + row3.GetValue<string>("username"));
                //Result keyspace_1 without table  user_from_keyspace_1

                IDseSession session2 = cluster.Connect("keyspace_2");
                Row row2 = session2.Execute("select * from user_by_id").First();
                Console.WriteLine("keyspace_2 without table " + row2.GetValue<string>("username")); 
                //Result keyspace_2 without table  user_from_keyspace_2



            }
            {

                IDseCluster cluster = DseCluster.Builder()
                              .AddContactPoint("myPoint")
                              .Build();
                IDseSession session2 = cluster.Connect("keyspace_1");
                var table2 = new Table<UserByIdModel>(session2);
                var user2 = table2.Execute().ToList().First();
                Console.WriteLine("keyspace_1 using table " + user2.UserName);
                //Result keyspace_1 using table user_from_keyspace_1


                IDseSession session = cluster.Connect("keyspace_2");
                var table = new Table<UserByIdModel>(session);
                var user = table.Execute().ToList().First();
                Console.WriteLine("keyspace_2 using table " + user.UserName); 
                //Result keyspace_2 using table user_from_keyspace_1


            }
        }
    }
```

please, help me =)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should introduce one different class per different table. The [Linq component of the DataStax driver](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/latest/features/components/linq/) will use the configuration defined when creating the `Table<T>` instance to determine to which keyspace/table it maps to. When using `new Table<UserByIdModel>(ISession session)` constructor, the mapping configuration used is the reusable `MappingConfiguration.Global` instance.

That said, the Linq component supports mapping multiple tables in different keyspaces per model using [the specific constructor](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/csharp/3.2/html/M_Cassandra_Data_Linq_Table_1__ctor_3.htm):

```
var config = MappingConfiguration.Global;
const string table = "user_by_id";
var table1 = new Table<UserByIdModel>(session1, config, table, "keyspace_1");
var table2 = new Table<UserByIdModel>(session2, config, table, "keyspace_2");
```